# Programmatically set which labels can grow in Crystal reports 2008

Tags: stored-procedures, formatting, crystal-reports-2008

I am attempting to programmatically set which lines on a Crystal report (2008) can and cannot grow. This is needed because the existing report has some pretty complex formatting and I do not want to set all the existing Labels to can grow. Just the one with an specific reference that is fed in from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this for a while I discovered that you can programmaticly set the CanGrow property as follows .

Right click on the label and select format field, 
Then select the common tab. 
Click on the CanGrow Formula entry button.

I then used the following code to allow an single label to grow bigger than one line :

```
if ({dp_LC3080_Retrieve;1.Reference} = "10") then
    true
else
   false
```